# Get albums and their covers at the same time?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

guys, I want to make a facebook gallery demo by using Graph API,
first step, I get user's albums through userID/albums/,
then I get album info like

```
 {"data": 
                [
                    {
                    "id": "338983769527169",
                    "from": 
                        {
                        "name": "Wonder Share",
                        "id": "100002466477281"
                        },
                    "name": "Wondershare Panorama Photos",
                    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=338983769527169&id=100002466477281&aid=77415",
                    "cover_photo": "420783901347155",
                    "privacy": "friends",
                    "count": 45,
                    "type": "app",
                    "created_time": "2012-09-06T02:36:13+0000",
                    "updated_time": "2013-03-14T01:29:38+0000",
                    "can_upload": false
                    }
                 ],
                 "paging": 
                 {
                 "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/100002466477281/albums?limit=25&after=MjkxMTk1MTYwOTcyNjk3"
                 }
             }
```

then I only have cover_photo ids, I need to get photo info by request the info API, this become 
very inconvenient if I want to show dozens of albums , for example , if user has 20 albums, first, I need to request these album ids , then request cover_photo info for each album, that is to say, I need to make 21 requests, this seem to be stupid.

Is there any solution to solve this problem ? Thanks a lot .

Comment: Any one know this ? help ! It has confused me for several days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/  (Go down to 'Specifying dependencies between operations in the request')

You can use a Batch request. You would first get the albums and then with the results from that request, take the album id's and use those to get the cover for each album. All this can be done in one call :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ,  could you be so kind as to give me some code about how to use Batch request with NSURLRequest or ASIHttpRequest ?

Comment: curl \
     -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'batch=[{ "method":"GET","name":"get-friends", "relative_url":"me/friends?limit=5", "omit_response_on_success":false,}, { "method":"GET", "relative_url":"?ids={result=get-friends:$.data.*.id}"}]' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/       I really have no idea about this code,I know what this means,but don't know how to use it,

Comment: You would send that request like any other request you send to graph.facebook.com. What have you tried so far and what errors are you getting back?